# Quero fazer a div "text" sumir quando passar o mouse em cima da img "HTML5" e ao mesmo tempo fazer a div"text2" aparecer no lugar

Tags: css, html5

```
<div class="banner">
        <div id="text">
            <h2>Quem sou ?</h2>
            <p>Sou um desenvolvedor web dominante das linguagens <strong>JavaScript</strong>, <strong>Python</strong>, <strong>Css3</strong> e <strong>Html5. </strong>Támbém possuo conhecimento nos frameworks <strong>Django</strong>, <strong>Flask</strong> e <strong>Angular</strong>. Valorizo meu trabalho e conhecimento e quero usa-los com as pessoas certas e com a equipe certa, com o objetivo de evoluir não só na carreira mas também a empresa.
            <h3>VAMOS TRABALHAR JUNTOS</h3> </p>
        </div>
        <div id="image"><img src="imagens/8a8c59e8-057a-4708-bc1f-9dba35862262-removebg-preview.png" alt="Myself"></div>

        <div style="display: none;" id="text2">
            <h2>Quais são as minhas habilidades ?</h2>
            <p>Assim como todo programador de desenvolvimento web precisa saber, possuo profundo conhecimento em <strong>HTML5</strong>, sendo capaz de fazer qualquer execução em <strong>HTML5</strong>.</p>
        </div>
        <div style="display: none;" id="image2"><img src="imagens/8a8c59e8-057a-4708-bc1f-9dba35862262-removebg-preview.png" alt="Myself"></div>
    </div>
   </header>
   <p class="pom">Passe O Mouse</p>
   <div id="linguages">
    <img id="HTML5" src="imagens/HTML5.png" alt="Html5">
    <img src="imagens/CSS3.png" alt="Css3">
    <img src="imagens/PYTHON.png" alt="Python">
    <img src="imagens/JAVASCRIPT.png" alt="Javascript">
    <img src="imagens/GIT.png" alt="Git">
    <img style=" filter: invert(100%);" src="imagens/OUTROS.png" alt="Outras Habilidades">
   </div>
```

Comment: Somos um Q&A, um catalogo de perguntas e respostas detalhadas, objetivas e específicas cujo a intenção é permitir a outros usuários, hoje e no futuro, que por meio de fermentas de automação encontrem soluções a problemas análogos aos que tiver. Da forma que está formulada a pergunta só o atende não sendo possível ser reaproveitada. Queremos que se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão o ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045), [ask] e faça o nosso [tour].

Comment: Quanto ao seu problema veja [Evento mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event). Caso esse fragmento seja parte de curriculum real tenho criticas a respeito mas não sei se está disposto a as receber.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve fazer uma função JavaScript para modificar display.

```
function changeDisplay(id, newDisplay) {
   document.getElementById(id).style.display = newDisplay;
}
```

Depois, faça uma outra função para indicar o que acontece quando voce coloca ou retira o mouse. Essa função deve receber como argumentos o id da div que vai mostrada e o id da div que vai ser escondida. Dessa forma aqui:

```
function hideAndShow(hide,show){
   changeDisplay(hide, 'none')
   changeDisplay(show,'block')
}
```

Em seguida, no html, dentro da div "image", você deve adicionar um atributo onmousemove devendo indicar o que acontece quando voce passa o mouse e outro atributo onmouseleave indicando o que deve acontecer quando você retirar o mouse da imagem. Dessa maneira aqui:

```
<div id="image2" onmousemove="hideAndShow('text1','text2')" onmouseleave="hideAndShow('text2','text1')" )><img src="imagens/8a8c59e8-057a-4708-bc1f-9dba35862262-removebg-preview.png" alt="Myself"></div>
```